# Memory problems with C

Tags: c, memory, codeblocks

Hello and have a good day, I've come here after days of trial and error so forgive me if I'm beign silly.

I have the following code. The idea of this code is first of all read all the files I have and store all the data into a matrix `Nsites`x`Nx`x`Ny` and then use the data for other unrelated things.

The amount of data is not very much, I mean i have 800 files of data which occupe no more than 80MB but anyway if I try to use a number for `DataFiles` higher than 134 I get a *Segmentation Fault error*.

I think it's weird because if it works with a number of `DataFiles=100` why it should'nt work for higher?

I thought it was because for a reason my program does not get enough memory allocated for the process or because I'm having an issue when allocating the memory. But I always have the same amount of data and my data files have exactly `88*44` values and working only until 134 files it's... I don't have experience with "high amount" of data/memory usage but I think that `1000*88*44` which is about `10^6` double digits it's not too much.

I'm using GCC compiler and Ubuntu (14.02 I think), when I try to compile and execute this program in Windows using Codeblocks it just crashes (another mistery).

Oh I also had a terminal open with RAM memory usage and with 134 files it was nothing big to handle for the computer.

EDIT: I also tried making several `[100][Nx][Ny]` arrays and use them one by one but that also lead to the *Segmentation Fault error*.
EDIT2: minor erratas text and code
Also, I'm following this way because I need all that data simultaneously... I'm thinking of new ways of avoiding this but last couple days did'nt find any alternative.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


const int   Nx=88;          //
const int   Ny=44;          //
const int   DataFiles=100;  // How many data files are we going to read 


int main() {
int i, j, ki , kj ,index;
double fun[DataFiles][Nx][Ny], Res[DataFiles][Nx][Ny],mean[Nx][Ny];
FILE * conf;
char file[100];

for (index=0; index<DataFiles; index++){

    sprintf(file,"data//file%i00.txt",5000+index*25);
    conf=fopen(file,"r");

    for(ki=0;ki<Nx;ki++){
        for(kj=0;kj<Ny;kj++){

            fscanf(conf,"%i %i %lf", &i, &j, &fun[index][ki][kj]);
            mean[ki][kj] = mean[ki][kj] + fun[index][ki][kj] ;

    }}
fclose (conf);
}
// do things with my loaded data
}
```

Comment: Your two arrays `fun` and `Res` are 6195200 bytes in total. On Linux the default stack is 8MB. You're cutting it awfully close.

Comment: You should probably close the files after you finished reading.

Comment: You don't check if `fopen` succeeds!

Comment: Do you need the data from all files in memory simultaneously? Is it enough with the data from just a single file, or possibly a few files?

Comment: a StackOverflow question on StackOverflow. Loop: see iteration. Iteration: see loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran out of stack. Generally speaking, don't allocate more than 8k at once on the stack. Oops.

Change

```
double fun[DataFiles][Nx][Ny], Res[DataFiles][Nx][Ny],mean[Nx][Ny];
```

To

```
double (*fun)[Nx][Ny] = malloc(sizeof(fun[0]) * DataFiles), (*Res)[Nx][Ny] = malloc(sizeof(Res[0]) * DataFiles), mean[Nx][Ny];
if (!fun || !Res) {
    /* handle OOM */
}
```

Comment: If i try this code with pure copy-paste it does'nt compile it says `error:variable-sized object may not be initialized`. I'm gonna look closer at it but I still dont understand malloc well enough yet.

Also I dont understand why I can't do it but I am relieved, thank you very much, sincerely.

Comment: I still can't find how to make this work, I can't declare a matrix with `malloc` ?

Comment: @fdzglln: I had to look it up myself. It turns out the type needs parenthesis to work.